# PostgreSQL json array of objects, default 0 values for properties if not found

Tags: postgresql, json

So my query looks like this:

```sql
select dk.product_id, dk.product_name,
  json_agg(
    json_build_object('location', dr.location, 'quantity', dr.quantity))::jsonb stock
from dax.dx_k dk 
left join dax.dx_r dr on dr.product_id= dk.product_id
where dr.location in ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')
group by product_name, product_id
order by product_id
```

And this results in:

```
00015   
TEST PRODUCT NAME   
[
  {"location": "A", "quantity": 15000.000000000000}, 
  {"location": "B", "quantity": 0.000000000000}
]
```

And my goal is to get the stock for all locations even if it doesn't have a record for `C` and `D` I'd like to return `C = 0` and `D = 0`.

Like this:

```
[
  {"location": "A", "quantity": 1500}, 
  {"location": "B", "quantity": 0},
  {"location": "C", "quantity": 0}, 
  {"location": "D", "quantity": 0}
]
```

Is there a simple way to do this, because I don't want to overcomplicate the query unnecessarily?

**UPDATE**:

I have another table called `sites` which contains the `locations` to any given `site` and I'll include my `site_id` in the `WHERE` clause, e.g.

```
...
WHERE site_id = 1
```

will result in:

```
site_id|location
1      |A
1      |B
1      |C
1      |D
```

And I'll need all locations for the given site:

```
[
  {"location": "A", "quantity": 1500}, 
  {"location": "B", "quantity": 0},
  {"location": "C", "quantity": 0}, 
  {"location": "D", "quantity": 0}
]
```

The problem with this is that I have my products associated with the locations in `dx_r` on `product_id`.

Comment: Unrelated, but: you don't need the cast `::jsonb`  if you use the corresponding `jsonb_` functions: `jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object(...))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO You can't get this outcome with the current data.

Given this sample data:

```
create table product (product_id int, product_name text);
create table stock (product_id int, location text, quantity int);

insert into product values (1, 'Product 1');
insert into stock values (1, 'a', 10), (1, 'b', 20);
```

You can't get locations `c` and `d` because there is not such information in your data:

```
select 
    dk.product_id, 
    dk.product_name,
    dr.location,
    dr.quantity
from 
    product dk 
left join 
    stock dr 
    on dr.product_id = dk.product_id;

product_id | product_name | location | quantity
---------: | :----------- | :------- | -------:
         1 | Product 1    | a        |       10
         1 | Product 1    | b        |       20
```

You should add a new (or existing) table of `locations`, or a table valued function, just to be able to get the required data.

```
create table location (id text);
insert into location values ('a'),('b'),('c'),('d'),('e'),('f');
```

Now you can use a sub-query to get this information:

```
select 
    p.product_id,
    p.product_name,
    (
    select 
        json_agg(
            json_build_object('location', l.id, 
                              'quantity', coalesce(s.quantity, 0)))::jsonb stock
    from
        location l
    left join
        stock s
        on s.location = l.id
        and s.product_id = p.product_id
    where
        l.id in ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
    ) stock
from
    product p
```

> ```
> product_id | product_name | stock                                                                                                                                     
> ---------: | :----------- | :-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>          1 | Product 1    | [{"location": "a", "quantity": 10}, {"location": "b", "quantity": 20}, {"location": "c", "quantity": 0}, {"location": "d", "quantity": 0}]
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=5aa52909f5de91bbbaf6a6f5c857fcfe)*

**Update**

You can use `sites` table for that purpose in this way:

```
select 
    dk.product_id,
    dk.product_name,
    (
    select 
        json_agg(
            json_build_object('location', s.location,
                              'quantity', coalesce(dr.quantity, 0)))::jsonb stock
    from
        sites s
    left join
        stock dr
        on dr.location = s.location
        and dr.product_id = dk.product_id
    where
        s.site_id = 1
    ) stock
from
    product dk;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=f1b30ece91f1415659142481d912e7a6)*

Comment: I've updated my question, maybe it'll be possible with that extra table.

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for!